# Is it possible to change the order of the context menu in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Iwonder if it's possible to change the order of the context menu inside firefox? I would like the option "Open link in new tab" to appear at the top when I right click a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the personal menu extension page, i found this other extension that actually lets you edit the order of context menu: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/710 (it is called "menu editor").

Comment: Nowadays the link to Menu Editor is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can customize all menus with the [Personal Menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3895) extension (original Russian link [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/3895)).

Comment: Nice one! Updated the link to be English (but kept your Russian as well).

Comment: Sorry, the plugin description is english and I wasn't pay attention to page language :)

Comment: but personal menu edits the menus in menubar, not in context menu (the one that shows up on right-click). right?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean as part of a web application you're building, not really, no. You may be able to from within a Firefox extension.

If you mean for your own purposes, that would be a question best asked over on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). My guess is it would involve something in the depths of one of Firefox's various JavaScript files (firefox.js, etc.), using an [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3895) like the one ZhuckovRA mentioned, or compiling Firefox yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I don't think a web application would be able to do that, considering that this question regards web programming, right? Otherwise, it's not a question for StackOverflow.

If you really need this, build your own context menu using JavaScript - but bear in mind, that you won't be able to rebuild the context menu entirely, and also, that some users may find this annoying.

Having that in mind, look at this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Context_Menu.aspx

http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-context-menu-tutorial.htm

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-context-menu.html

Found it with a quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Ada%3Aofficial&hs=iCU&q=javascript+custom+context+menu&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g1).